# Перечисление в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть некое перечисление в строке, например:

TSTK-345, TSTK-9995, TSTK-1 И т.п.

как проверить с помощью регулярного выражения что в строке есть запятая, при том что строка может содержать при первой записи только TSTK-345 и рег. выражение должно пропускать первое вхождение значения в строку, но не пропускать если будет "TSTK-345TSTK-9995", а пропускать если будет "TSTK-345, TSTK-9995, TSTK-1 И т.п."

Comment: чтобы проверить наличие запятой в строке, регулярное выражение не нужно. Вам нужно от первой запятой и дальше, и в случае отсутствия запятой - исходную строку, или что?

Comment: Насколько я понял, нужно проверить, есть ли буквы после цифр, и если есть, отделены ли они запятой?

Comment: `^TSTK-345(?:, ?TSTK-\d+)*$` попробуйте так, а еще лучше заполните вопрос согласно описанию в метке, там же есть справочник.

Comment: По сути да нужно проверить если запятая после цифр, но вот в чем беда первая запись может быть без запятой в конце переменная строка может сохранить только TSTK-345 и это будет истина, проверить можно я так понял например так:     .*,.*    но такое выражение обязательно будет искать запятые во всем выражении и если их нет отдаст лож, хотя первое вхождение в строку TSTK-345 у меня истина

Comment: @HANTRHANTR отмечайте пользователя сообщества так же как отметил я вас, пользователю придет оповещение, а другие будут знать кому адресовано сообщение

Comment: @PotroNik хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty да вы правы, но немного по другому запятая после цифры, а не буква, кроме первой так как первая TSTK-345 может быть единственной записью в  строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение

```
^TSTK-345(?:, ?TSTK-\d+)*$
```

Раз уж ЯП не заполнен, то приведу пример работы на js:
Передаем 5 строки:

> TSTK-345,TSTK-9995,TSTK-1
> TSTK-345
> TSTK-345TSTK-9995
> TSTK-345 TSTK-9995
> TSTK-345, TSTK-9995, TSTK-1

```js
const regex = /^TSTK-345(?:, ?TSTK-\d+)*\h*$/gm;
const str = `
TSTK-345,TSTK-9995,TSTK-1
TSTK-345
TSTK-345TSTK-9995
TSTK-345 TSTK-9995
TSTK-345, TSTK-9995, TSTK-1
`;
result = str.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

---

Подробности:
`^TSTK-345(?:, ?TSTK-\d+)*$`
`^` - символ начала строки
`TSTK-345` - статичный набор символов
`(?:...)*` - не захватываемая группа, нужна для указания последовательности 0 и более раз
`, ?` - запятая и один или ноль символов пробела
`TSTK-` - статичный набор символов
`\d+` - одна и более цифр
`$` - конец строки

Comment: Спасибо, язык я не стал заполнять так как его мало кто знает это SIL проверка через рутину matches https://anovaapps.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SIL/pages/1828656/matches